# HTML template - assigning html data

Tags: javascript, html, templates, html-dataset

I am using HTML  for the first time in combination with an AJAX call. Is it possible assign html data to a div using JavaScript?

I have the following:

```
<template class="template result student">
    <div class="result student" data-category="student">
        <div class="box name">
            <span class="name">John Smith</span>
            <br />
            <span class="category">Student</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And JS

```
const studentTemplate = 
    document.querySelector(".template.result.student"),
    category = studentTemplate.dataset.querySelector(".result.student"),
    studentName = studentTemplate.content.querySelector(".box.name .name"),
    date = studentTemplate.content.querySelector(".box.dob .date");

   category.textContent    = "student";
   studentName.textContent = "student name";
```

So as you can see I am trying to set date-student in the template via JS. But I get

```
studentTemplate.dataset.querySelector is not a function
```

Question is, what is correct way of doing this? Setting the content works fine

Comment: See my updated answer for accessing and modifying the `dataset` value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `content` property to access content of the template.

The `dataset` property is for accessing `data-` html attributes and would be followed with the name of the attribute, as in `dataset.category`. As the error states, `querySelector()` is not a valid method on the data object returned from the `dataset` property.

```js
const studentTemplate = document.querySelector(".template.result.student");
var category = studentTemplate.content.querySelector(".result.student");
var studentName = studentTemplate.content.querySelector(".box.name .name")
var dte = studentTemplate.content.querySelector(".box.dob .date");

// Modify the text content of the elements
category.textContent    = "teacher";
studentName.textContent = "teacher name";

// Modify the data-category attribute value of the the div
category.dataset.category = "teacher";
console.log(category);
```

```html
<template class="template result student">
    <div class="result student" data-category="student">
        <div class="box name">
            <span class="name">John Smith</span>
            <br />
            <span class="category">Student</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```